# .htaccess rewrite /files/users/1/file.pdf to /view/?file=file.pdf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am terrible with `mod_rewrite` however I need to rewrite any request to the folder `/files/users/*/` (* is a wildcard) to `/view/` and insert the filename into a query paramater like so:

`/files/users/9/test.pdf` becomes `/view/?file=test.pdf`

How would I go about this assuming that the `.htaccess` file will be located inside `/files/users/`?

I would really appreciate if you explained how your solution works as I am slowly trying to become familiar with `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you wanna have all my trade secrets on a silver plate?

Well, I try my best. ;-)

First of all, you must know where the documentation is. Look here for the reference: [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Or [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), if your Apache version is 2.2.

You will find an overview with lots of links at [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). There, you will find a nice [introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) to rewriting URLs. Also look here for lots of standard examples.

Since mod_rewrite supports PCRE regular expressions, you might need [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and/or [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) from time to time.

Now to your question

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:.+?)/(.*) /view/?file=$1
```

This might already be sufficient. It looks for a subdirectory `(?:.+?)` in `/files/users` and captures the name of a file `(.*)` in this subdirectory. If this pattern matches, it rewrites the URL to `/view/?file=` and appends the captured file with `$1`, which gives `/view/?file=$1`.

All untested, of course, have fun.

P.S. Additional info is here at SO at [.htaccess info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info) and [.htaccess faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess?sort=faq).

Answer (score 0):

Put the directive below in your `.htaccess` file to **rewrite** `/files/users/9/test.pdf` to `/view/?file=test.pdf`. In practical terms this means that if you visit http://yourdomain.com/files/users/9/test.pdf then the visitor will be served the *rewritten url* which is http://yourdomain.com/view?file=test.pdf

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /view/?file=$1 [L]
```

A [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive is part of the Apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module. It takes two arguments:

1. *Pattern* - a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match against the current URL path (note that the URL path is not the entire URL but eg. **/my/path**, but in a `.htaccess` context the leading slash **/** is stripped giving us **my/path**).
2. *Substitution* - the destination URL or path where the user will rewritten OR redirected to.

### Explaining the rule

The pattern `^[^/]+/(.*)$`:

```
^    - the regex must match from the start of the string
[^/] - match everything but forward slash 
+    - repetition operator which means: match 1 or more characters
/    - matches a forward slash
(.*) - mathes any characters. The dot means match any character. The star operator means match ANY characters (0 or more). The parantheses means the match is grouped and can be used in backreferences.
$    - the regex must match until the end of the string
```

The substitution `/view/?file=$1`:

...means that we rewrite the URL path to the `/view/` folder with the query parameter file. The query parameter `file` will contain our first grouped match from the *pattern* as we pass it the `$1` value (which means the first match from our RewriteRule pattern).

The `[L]` flag:

...means that *mod_rewrite* will stop processing rewrite rules. This is handy to avoid unwanted behaviour and/or infinite loops.